# Java 8 stream groupingBy String value

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a JSON file containing data in the form:

```
{
    "type":"type1",
    "value":"value1",
    "param": "param1"
}
{
    "type":"type2",
    "value":"value2",
    "param": "param2"
}
```

I also have an object like this:

```
public class TestObject {
    private final String value;
    private final String param;

    public TestObject(String value, String param) {
        this.value = value;
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```

What I want is to create a `Map<String, List<TestObject>>` that contains a list of `TestObject`s for each type.

This is what I coded:

```
Map<String, List<TestObject>> result = jsonFileStream
                .map(this::buildTestObject)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> JsonPath.read(line, "$.type")));
```

Where the method `buildTestObject` is:

```
private TestObject buildTestObject(String line) {
    return new TestObject(
               JsonPath.read(line, "$.value"),
               JsonPath.read(line, "$.param"));
}
```

This does not work because the `map()` function returns a `TestObject`, so that the `collect` function does not work on the JSON String line anymore.

In real life, I cannot add the "type" variable to the `TestObject`file, as it is a file from an external library.

How can I group my `TestObject`s by the type in the JSON file?

Comment: It’s trivial with a for loop. There’s no reason to use a stream at all.

Comment: Maybe create a class that's exactly the same as `TestObject` (or just extend `TestObject` if you can), but with the extra `type` property? And then you deserialise your JSON into an instance of this class, group it, and then map it to the original `TestObject`?

Comment: Yes, I could use a for loop. Yes, I could create a new object that would be a composition of TestObject. I find the streams elegant and I was wondering if it could be done that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the mapping operation to a down stream collector of groupingBy:

```
Map<String, List<TestObject>> result = jsonFileStream
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(line -> JsonPath.read(line, "$.type"),
        Collectors.mapping(this::buildTestObject, Collectors.toList())));
```

This will preserve the string so you can extract the type as a classifier, and applies the mapping to the elements of the resulting groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `toMap` collector to accomplish the task at hand.

```
Map<String, List<TestObject>> resultSet = jsonFileStream
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(line -> JsonPath.read(line, "$.type"),
                  line -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(buildTestObject(line))),
                  (left, right) -> {
                      left.addAll(right);
                      return left;
                 }
           ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601055/3973077) solution, it's worth pointing out that Java 8 also significantly improved the `Map` interface, making this kind of thing 
much less painful to achieve with a `for` loop than had previously been the case. I am not familiar with the library you are using, but something like this will work (you can always convert a `Stream` to an `Iterable`).

```
Map<String, List<TestObject>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(JsonPath.read(line, "$.type"), k -> new ArrayList<>())
       .add(buildTestObject(line)); 
}
```